# Bootstrap ipad not showing like mobile

Tags: html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, ipad

I just made a simple navbar and i looked on my mobile and it looks just normal like this: http://prntscr.com/dbjxgd, (the mobile version) But on my iPad mini 2 it looks like the desktop version which looks like this: http://prntscr.com/dbjxpe
What is causing this? I just want my iPad to show the mobile version. Can you guys help me? Here is some code i used if u need it:

Code: index.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Servicepunt Detailhandel Groningen | Home</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<body>
<!-- NAVIGATIE BALK -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<!-- logo -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <!--  -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
    Logo
  </a>

  <!-- Inklappbaar ding als je op mobiel zit-->
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainnavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
</div>

<!-- menu eitems  linker kant-->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainnavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

    <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="paginas/Over/index.php">Over</a></li>
    <li><a href="paginas/Nieuws/index.php">Nieuws</a></li>
    <li><a href="paginas/Contact/index.php">Contact</a></li>

    <!-- Dropdown -->
    <!--
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Profiel <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Profiel</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Instellingen</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    -->
    <!-- <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg raised">Niet beschikbaar</button></li> -->
  </ul>


  <!-- Aan de rechterkant -->


</nav>

<!-- EINDE NAVIAGTIE BALK-->
HOME



</body>
</html>
```

Code: style.css

```
textarea {
font-family: "Verdana";
resize: none;
width: 400px;
height: 50px;
}

label {
font-weight: normal;
}
input {
font-weight: normal;
}

.navbar-default {
background-color: white;
box-shadow: 20px;
padding: 15px;
border-radius: 0;
border: none;
font-size: 25px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 3px -2px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 3px -2px #999;
         box-shadow: 0 5px 3px -2px #999;
}

.navbar-header{
right: auto;
}

.navbar-nav > li{
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;

}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: black;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;

}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #FFF;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
border-color: none;
}

.icon-bar {
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 40px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 20px;

}

.navbar-collapse {
border: 0px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
color: #e7e7e7;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
border-color: transparent;
box-shadow: none;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
color: blue;
}
```

I hope you guys can help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
}
```

and to target for ipad use below media query refer more detaild [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

```
/* ----------- iPad mini ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* ----------- iPad 1 and 2 ----------- */
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* ----------- iPad 3 and 4 ----------- */
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}
```

Comment: It workes but that just extends it. Now people with a smaller resolution then 1200 show the mobile version. I want people with a laptop to show the desktop but if they are on any mobile device to show the mobile? Is this even possible with bootstrap? I'm quite new so i dont know much

Comment: Yes what you are saying is possible. You have to use media queries specific to Ipad. You can find alot of them here : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: It works in portrait mode. In landscape mode its just the desktop version. But if u do it with mediaqueries it simply says that if your  screen is smaller then 1200 pixels it shows the mobile version. I dont know if some laptops are smaller then that? But if i do the media querie with the 1200px the person with that small laptop gets to see the mobile version. Is there another way maybe? Its okay like this but i want something more secure if you know what i mean

Answer (score 0):

You dont' need to add any css code yourself. You have to download the bootstrap version with your updated breakpoint.

go to : **http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system** and change the **@grid-float-breakpoint** to the width you want your navbar to collapse. You can enter any value in pixels. use @screen-lg-min or anything else.

And then click the Compile and Download Button at the bottom.